# Calculate the sequence using its sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I've wanted to solve this simple problem for the sequence $(u_{n})_{n\ge 0}$ such that

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}u_{k}=\frac{n^2+n}{3}$.

I tried doing $\sum_{k=0}^{n}u_{k}=\frac{n^2+n}{3} = \frac{2}{3}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{3}+2+\cdots+\frac{2n}{3}$,

so, logically:

$u_0=0, u_1=\frac{2}{3}, u_2=\frac{4}{3},u_3=2,\cdots,u_n=\frac{2n}{3}$.

But I couldn't find any relationship between the different terms of $(u_{n})$ so I can't know for sure the formula of the sequence in terms of $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is there a trick to guess the literal expression of $(u_{n})$? Or is there a problem with my take?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: consider the difference between the sum for n and n-1. That's exactly the term you need to add to get from n-1 to n

Comment: Ok, I see it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}u_{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_{k}=\frac{n^2+n}{3}-\frac{(n-1)^2+(n-1)}{3}=\frac  {2n} 3$